# Can someone explains why i cant add gradient style dinamicly?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, frontend

This is my first question here, I need help.

The background is set to `linear-gradient`
I want to style the input range to change gradient when the user moves it.

I have variable `color`, `color` holds the value of gradient based on the value of the input.
My variable color is changing, but for some reason, I cant add it to CSS.

This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


  <body onload="myF()">
  <input 
  type="range"
  value="0" 
  min="0" 
  max="10000" 

  id="mySlider" 
  class="slider">

 <h4>
 <span class="price" id="value">0</span>
 / month
</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS :

```
 .slider{
 margin: 2rem auto;
 width: 60%;
 height: 13px;

 border-radius: 7px;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0, 255, 200) 20% ,  rgb(219, 219, 219)20%);

 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 outline: none;
 }
 /* SLIDER THUMB FOR GOOGLE CHROME */
 .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: black;
 ocutline: none;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 /* SLIDER THUMB FOR MOZILA-FIREFOX */
.slider::-moz-range-thumb{
height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color:  rgb(0, 255, 200);
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 .price{
 font-size: 2rem;
 display: inline;
 }
```

I have function `myF()`, i added it to the body with `<body onload="myF()">`, in that function i have two things

1. function that displays the value of the slider
2. function that should change gradient based on input (it doesn't work).
   I have 2 logs for you to see.
   slider.style.background logs empty string.
   and color logs current gradient witch is good.

And this is my script:

```
  function myF(){
  var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
   var output = document.getElementById("value");


   let update = () => output.innerHTML =  "$"   +  (slider.value/100) ;

  slider.addEventListener('input', update);
  update();


   slider.addEventListener('mousemove' , () =>{

   var x = (slider.value/100);
   var color = 'linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0, 255, 200)' + x + 
      '% ,  rgb(219, 219, 219)' + x +   '%);' ;

    slider.style.background = color ;

   /* for some reason frst log is good value but second log is EMPTY STRING */

    console.log(color);
    console.log(slider.style.background);
  
    } )
    } ;
```

I uploaded all of this to GitHub and it's live on git-pages.

git-hub  https://github.com/Shomy032/Slider.git

live  https://shomy032.github.io/Slider/

Once again this is my first question here, sorry for any inconvenience :)

Comment: The semicolon in the string is breaking it. Use `'linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0, 255, 200)' + x + 
      '% ,  rgb(219, 219, 219)' + x +   '%)' ;` instead

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are adding `;` at the end of your color, which is not allowed therefore it won't accept that value.

removing the `;` will fix your problem.

here you have your code working.

```js
function myF() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
  var output = document.getElementById("value");


  let update = () => output.innerHTML = "$" + (slider.value / 100);

  slider.addEventListener('input', update);
  update();


  slider.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {

    var x = (slider.value / 100);
    var color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 255, 200)' + x +
      '%,  rgb(219, 219, 219)' + x + '%)';

    slider.style.background = color;

  })
}
```

```css
.slider {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 255, 200) 20%, rgb(219, 219, 219)20%);
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}


/* SLIDER THUMB FOR GOOGLE CHROME */

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  ocutline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* SLIDER THUMB FOR MOZILA-FIREFOX */

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 200);
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.price {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body onload="myF()">
  <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10000" id="mySlider" class="slider">

  <h4>
    <span class="price" id="value">0</span> / month
  </h4>

</body>

</html>
```